# PHP basic database link help

Tags: php, hyperlink

i want to fetch a field from database eg. "name" and then use it as a link to display further info about that name from the database itself
i used -

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

echo"<a href=\"test.php?id=1\">{$re["name"]}'</a>'";

    }
```

but i want that each 'name' entry when fetched from database be assigned different id like-
adam id=1
chris id=2 
so that in the next page i can GET that id and display contents accordingly.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your current example to keep a count like this:

```
$id = 0;

while($re=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $id++;
     echo"<a href=\"test.php?id={$id}\">{$re["name"]}'</a>'";
}
```

Comment: Awsomeeee just what i wanted!Thankss!

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<a href=\"test.php?id={$row['id']}\">".htmlspecialchars($row['name'])."</a>\n";
}
```

Assuming you have an `id` column in the database, all you need to do is include that field in the results of the `SELECT` query and echo it along with your existing code.

You should have an auto-incrementing primary key in your database that you will use in the `SELECT` query on your next page, and all you need to do is use this as your `id`.

If you don't have a numeric primary key, add one. If for some reason you can't, use the `name` field as the `id` and select by that instead.

A couple of side notes:

- Make sure you escape the `name` field with [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to ensure you don;t break your output with user entries.
- Use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` - this is the right thing to do 99% of the time.
- You had extra single quotes surrounding your closing `</a>` - I have removed them in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just use the name itself as the id, and then on the next page use the name as your database query `WHERE` clause.  Since an integer id isn't known to your database, you cannot easily match it back up to the name.

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $name = $rs['name'];
  echo"<a href='test.php?name='" . urlencode($name) . "'>" . htmlentities($name) . "</a>";
}
```

On your other page...

```
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name');
```

This assumes, of course, that your names are unique.

Comment: i understood your idea but i didn't understand the code part of it?

Comment: thanks i tried but its not displaying anything on the second page:(

Comment: On the second page, you need to fill in the rest of what you want to do. I've only gotten you as far as the query. You need to retrieve the results and display them however necessary.

Comment: i did this -<?php
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page WHERE name='$name'"); 

while($re=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo $re['company'];